# How to change HTML background with JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, html, image, background

How to change HTML background with JavaScript Function? I need some simple function to change background from one image to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple like this:

```
function changeBGImage(){
     document.body.background = "image.jpg";
}
```

**UPDATE**

Or if you wanna use CSS (**more elegant solution**) with it, you could use:

```
<style>
.bg1 {
background-image: url(images/my_image.jpg); 
}
</style>

<body id="page_body">

<script>
function changeBGImage(whichImage){
     document.getElementById('page_body').className="bg"+whichImage;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well, for one thing "background" isn't a property of the `<body>` DOM object, at least not in all browsers. The CSS answer should work however and it's really the right way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
function newBackGround (element,background) {
   element.style.backgroundImage = "url("+background+")";
}

newBackground (myElement,"newBackground.jpg");
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative **IFF** using jquery

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url(/image.jpg)");
```

Comment: I think it's overkill to import an entire library (jQuery) only for this

Comment: That is correct HENCE why I put IFF (if and only if, AND in bold) jquery is being used!!

Answer (score 1):

## demo codes:

```js
element = document.querySelector("body");
element.style.backgroundImage =  "url('https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/logo/logo.png')";


elements = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for(let element of elements){
  element.style.background =  "url('https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/logo/logo.png')";
}
```

### reference links:

> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeBGImage(whichImage){
     document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + whichImage + ")";
}
```

Comment: @Pointy, he missed the `style` property, it should be `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + whichImage + ")";`

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers change the body.  The most direct way to change the html background is like so:

```
const imagePath = "/img/sub-folder/my-image.png";
document.documentElement.style.background = `url("${imagePath}")`;
```