# How to change background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I would like to create a site similar to http://www.tomford.com/ but in HTML.

the problem is how do I create a background where images

- change automatically background
- user clicks a icon to change background
- done in css or java script

What I have done:

```
<body style="background: url(url of image) repeat-x repeat-y center"></body>
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slideshow/ . no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change HTML background with JavaScript Function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618699/how-to-change-html-background-with-javascript-function)

Comment: Are you using an external stylesheet, or are all of your styles inline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by either setting the background image via jQuery/JS or by setting a class on the item and having the background images defined in the CSS.

To do the first, you can read through this thread: [change background image in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867503/change-background-image-in-body)

Basically

```
$('.icon').click(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/header-top.jpg)');
});
```

OR

```
$('.icon').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass().addClass('bg-1'); 
    //removes all classes, then adds the new class
});
```

Where `.icon` is whatever thing you want to click to trigger the change.

You would then just declare a background for `.bg1` in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in jquery this way

**JS CODE:**

```
var url="http://......."
$('...').on('click',function(){ 
    $('body').css('background:',url);
});
```

*Note: the click event can be called based on specific selector(class,id or tag name)*

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via CSS3 transitions, like shown [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3).