# How to change html td background colour through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style type="text/css">
    td.a{
        background: yellow
    }
</style>

<table><td class="a"></td></table>
```

Above is a html/css code snippet. From it, you can know that the background colour of td portion is in yellow.

Later, I have added a html select drop down component. I hope to change the background colour from yellow to blue when I select another select drop down value. but I do not know how to do.

This should be a question related to changing css through Javacript. It is quite similar with this [How to change HTML background with JavaScript Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618699/how-to-change-html-background-with-javascript-function) but u can see that my td component does not have id, it just has class.

Hope someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: Well, the obvious solution is to either give your `td` an `id`, or use `document.getElementByClassName`. **Edit:** for your [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing all elements with the class name

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor="blue";
}
```

Or to change a single element, as long as you know it's position.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
elements[positon].style.backgroundColor="blue";//in your example position would be 0
```

If you give your element an id you can use the following

```
document.getElementById("idforelement").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the colour you want to change the background of the cells (I'm assuming you'll have more than just the one) to is newColor then;

```
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
for (var x = 0; x < tds.length; x++) {
  tds[x].style.background = newColor;
}
```